# Is there a condition along with Strong convergence which gives convergence in norm?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $\{T_n\}$ be a sequence of operators in a Hilbert Space and $T_n$ converges to an operator $T$ in the strong operator topology. Is there any assumption which I can put on $\{T_n\}$ so that the SOT convergence will imply convergence in norm?